# sheduled task: pinned server list

Tags: wso2

I defined in wso2ei a scheduled task. It's based on the proxy-service 'scheduler'. The problem is the field 'pinned server list'. If I leave it empty or enter 'localhost' I got an empty page with the url eg https://12.34.56.78:9443/carbon/task/savetask-ajaxprocessor.jsp
and when load the url I got 'Error 405 - Method Not Allowed'. In 'system logs' an error shows up
'Error invoking setter method named : setMessage() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameterDid not find a setter method named : setMessage() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameter'

So I entered the wso2ei-server-IP eg 12.34.56.89 in the 'Pinned Servers' field. Now the scheduled task shows up in the list. But the 'Systems log' stated 'Server name not in pinned servers list. Not starting Task : BBO20Worker'

My questions are: 
- where can I find and manipulate the pinned server list?
- what is the name of my wso2ei server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The configured pinned server defines the server node that the scheduled task will be executed [1].

You can define a name for your service instance by adding the `-DSynapseServerName=<ServerName>` in the startup script (integrator.sh or integrator.bat file) [2]. Then use the defined server name as the pinned server name.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/WSO2EI/Adding+and+Scheduling+Tasks

[2] https://docs.wso2.com/display/WSO2EI/Working+with+Proxy+Services

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works. In the log - file the correct name is outputted. But I can not used it as server name in the defintion. Same behaviour as former described -> Error 405..

Comment: We are using wso2ei 6.1.1 in a SLES 11.1 environment. As stated in the last comment the server name is now correct but a new problem occured.

Comment: Follow up: The latter problem is also solved. It was caused by defining the task property 'message' as literal & plain text string. After replacing it with an empty xml-element eg <XX/> the problem disappeared. In the System Logs the error message was 'Error invoking setter method named : setMessage() that takes a single String, int, long, float, double or boolean parameter'

Comment: What exactly is a pinned server name? We tried with IPs and still does not work.

Comment: [2020-03-05 17:56:18,475]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.startup.quartz.StartUpController} - Server name not in pinned servers list. Not starting Task